# Inserting data into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm struggling with inserting data from the form to database. I managed to establish the connection (at least not getting any errors), but when comes to inserting values I facing error, I'm not sure if rows/columns of the table should be in ' ' or not, I've seen some examples both with quotation marks and without, and also if variables should have those as well.

connecting to the database (connect.php):

```
<?php
define("DB_SERVER","localhost");
define("DB_USER","root");
define("DB_PASS","");
define("DB_NAME","Bookshop");

$connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    if(!$connection){
        die("error: unable to connect to database " . mysql_error());
    }
    $select_db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $connection);
    if(!$select_db){
        die("error: unable to connect to database " . mysql_error());
    }
?>
```

including connections:

```
<?php
    include ("connect.php"); // connects to database
?>
```

and inserting data from the form:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO customer 
                (CUST_ID, CUST_NAME, CUST_SURNAME, HOUSE_NO, STREET, POSTCODE, PHONE_NO, EMAIL, OGIN, PASSWORD)
                VALUES 
                ('10101', '$forename', '$surname', '$address1', '$address2', '$postcode', 
                '$phone_no', '$email', '$login', '$password')"; 
mysql_query($query, $connection);

    if(!mysql_query($query, $connection)){
        echo "Error!!!!";
    }

mysql_close($connection);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are a newbie.. Start with mysqli or pdo extensions. Visit [W3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)  for a detailed explanantion with examples. Below is an example of how to use mysqli to connect and insert a row in your database

```
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

And For your query..

> I'm not sure if rows/columns of the table should be in ' ' or not,
>   I've seen some examples both with quotation marks and without, and
>   also if variables should have those as well.

As far as insert queries are concerned, 
1).Wrap up column names with ` back ticks.
2).Wrap your Variables with single quote nothing wrong in that

**For more understanding about single and double quote usages,**

*Single quotes does not look for variables while double quote does*

**Case 1 :**

```
    $value = 10;
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `column_name` = $value';
    echo $sql;
```

output is

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `column_name` = $value
```

Here if you see single quote does not look for a variable within it. Whatever there is inside single quotes, it is considered as a string and returned as such.

**Case 2:**

```
    $value = 10;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `column_name` = $value";
    echo $sql;
```

Output is

```
 SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `column_name` = 10
```

Here Since the query is inside double quotes, That variable is read. but considered as int.

**Case 3:**

```
    $value = 10;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `column_name` = '$value'";
    echo $sql;
```

Output is

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `column_name` = '10'
```

Here Since the query is inside double quotes, That variable is read. but considered as string as it is encapsulated with single quotes.